# Error creating macro trying to create a base table with fields already aliased

Tags: sql, jinja2, dbt

I am trying to create a macro that checks against all previous columns in all tables of a schema and alias if it is already present and if not lay the ground work for easy aliasing. I am getting an error stating "module 'dbt.exceptions' has no attribute 'RuntimeException'. So when I go and look into the logs I see
'dbt.context.providers.RuntimeDatabaseWrapper object' has no attribute 'list_relations'??? How would I list all the tables within a schema then to grab all the column names? I have attached my code below.

```
{% macro transform_source(schema_name,source_name, table_name, alias_prefix='') %}

{% set tables = adapter.list_relations(schema=schema_name, relation_type='table') %}
{% ad-%}

  {% set transformed_columns = [] %}
  {% for table in tables %}
    {% set table_columns = adapter.get_columns_in_relation(table_name=table.name) %}
    {% set lower = table_columns.lower() %}
    {% set transformed_columns = transformed_columns + [(lower, table_columns)] %}

  {% endfor %}


{%- set source_relation = source(source_name, table_name)-%}
{% set columns_source = adapter.get_columns_in_table(source_relation) %}

{% set source_columns = [] %}
{% for column in columns_Source %}
{% set column_name = column.name %}
{% set lower_name = column_name.lower() %}
{% set aliased_columns = aliased_columns + [(lower_name, aliased_column)] %}
{% endfor %}

{% set model %}
/* ============================================= 
Home Database: 
View/Table:

Author:
Create date:
Description:

Revision History: 
<Create Date, dt,> - (<Ticket Number:, str,>) - <Initials, str, JM> - Created.


============================================= */ 

WITH Source AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM {% raw %}{{ source({% endraw %}'{{ source_name }}', '{{ table_name }}'{% raw %}) }}{% endraw %}
    ),

    Renamed AS(
        SELECT
            {% for column_tuple in source_columns %}
            {% for aliased_columns in transformed_columns%}
            {% if column_tuple[0] == transformed_columns[0]%}
            {{ column_tuple[0] }} AS {{ transformed_columns[1] }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
            {% else %}
            {{column_tuple[0]}} AS   {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        FROM Source 
    )

    SELECT *
    FROM Renamed

{% endset %}

{% if execute %}

{{ log(model, info=True) }}
{% do return(model) %}

{% endif %}

{% endmacro %}
```

I tried several different ways of rewriting the script and I come back to the same sort of structure again and again. I am expecting the macro to print out the script within the CLI with columns that have already been used previously so I don't have to keep aliasing models when a similar column has previously been aliased already?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really follow what the rest of your macro is doing, but to answer your question, you can generate a list of Relation objects by using `dbt_utils`, specifically the [`get_relations_by_pattern`](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils#get_relations_by_pattern-source) macro:

```sql
{% set relations = dbt_utils.get_relations_by_pattern(schema_name, '%') %}
{% set tables = relations | selectattr("type", "equalto", "table") %}
```

Comment: I am trying to match previously aliased columns from all tables within a schema to a new base table I am trying to bring in. I thought it'd be easiest to lowercase both the incoming column and all columns to try and match them together then if that occurs give me the column name that is aliased. Else I would want a placeholder to know where I need to alias the column. I'm doing this to get in line with our camelcase naming convention and so I don't have to keep writing out like-named columns.

Comment: I now receive the following error from making that adjustment: "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'ilike' "

Comment: there's an issue with one of your arguments to the `get_relations_by_pattern` macro. Maybe `schema_name` is unset?